# want to change graphic by recognizing click down and up

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

```
button("", imageview("a.png")) {

}
```

I would like to change this button to `a_click.png` when I clickup, and return it to `a.png` when I clickdown.

I couldn't find a way to this event and change graphic. Help me..!

Answer (score 0):

```
button("", imageview("a.png")) {
    setOnMousePressed { graphic = imageview("a_click.png") }
    setOnMouseReleased { graphic = imageview("a.png") }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it